# может метод АОА работать с wi fi точкой доступа с 1-ой антенной?

Tags: методы, wifi, геолокация

может метод АОА работать  с   wi fi точкой доступа с 1-ой антенной?

Comment: Пожалуйста, конкретизируйте ваш вопрос. Как это сделать, можно прочитать в [Справке сообщества](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: я читал про метода АОА и написано что для работы нужны точки доступа с несколькими антенами и что метод АОА работает с мумимо точками доступов . так насколько эффективно и возможно  ли применить этот метод  для определения местоположения смартфона  с помошю точками доступов wi fi с 1-ой антеной ?

Comment: АОА не будет работать с одной или двумя антеннами.

Comment: дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1149904/насколько-будет-эффективно-применить-метод-позиционирования-АОА-для-локализации