# насколько будет эффективно применить метод позиционирования АОА для локализации смартфона с помощью точками доступов wi fi с одной антенной?

Tags: wifi, геолокация, позиционирование

возможно ли и насколько будет эффективно применить метод позиционирования АОА для локализации смартфона с помощью  точками  доступов  wi fi с одной антенной?
И даже если точки доступов wi fi  многоантенные и многоканальные возможно ли выполнить позиционирование если знаем что в основном  смартфоны поддерживают только 1 канал?

Answer (score 0):

АОА на одной антенне невозможно осуществить. минимум нужны 4 антенны установленные решеткой. Количество каналов и антенн на источнике значение не имеет.

Но имеет значение возможности софта и железа в приёмнике. Бытовые роутеры не могут определить угол приходящего сигнала изза того что аппаратно не учитывается и не используется Угол Приходящего Сигнала.

Аппаратно роутер должен поддерживать mumimo, иметь фазовую решетку на антеннах и передавать расчитанный угол в софтовую часть.

На бытовых роутерах возможно лишь триангуляция по мощности принимаемого сигнала.